# Decimals missing in result after adding up order totals for a customer

Tags: templating, plugin-craftcommerce, order

I want to show a user the total sum of all their orders.
My problem: In the result the decimals are "lost" and always show as zeros.

```
{% set totalOrders = 0 %}
{% for order in craft.commerce.orders.customer(craft.commerce.customer).find() %}
  {% set totalOrders = totalOrders + order.totalPrice|currency(order.currency) %}
{% endfor %}
{{ totalOrders|currency(order.currency) }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trouble you are running into is trying to add a string value to an integer to get your total.

You have to use `order.totalPrice` without the `currency` filter to be able to add all the values together.

```
{% set cart = craft.commerce.cart %}
{% set totalOrders = 0 %}

{% for order in craft.commerce.orders.customer( craft.commerce.customer ).find() %}
  {% set totalOrders = totalOrders + order.totalPrice %}
{% endfor %}

{{ totalOrders|currency( cart.currency ) }}
```

Only apply the `currency` filter once all the calculations are complete.